# Why pointer to non-const member function can't point const member function and opposite?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, function-pointers

What is the reason why pointers to member functions, can't point to const member functions?

```
struct A {
    void g() {};
    void f() const {}
};
```

Later in code:

```
void (A::* fun)() = &A::f;
```

This code produces:

```
error: cannot convert ‘void (A::*)()const’ to ‘void (A::*)()’ in initialization
```

Of course it compiles with `&A::g` instead of `&A::f`.

In opposite situation:

```
void (A::* fun)() const = &A::g;
```

The error is:

```
error: cannot convert ‘void (A::*)()’ to ‘void (A::*)()const’ in initialization
```

The second case is rather clear. `const` pointer isn't expected to modify the object so it can't hold the function which does it. But why it's not possible to assign `const` member function to `non-const` member function as in the first case?

It looks like the rule for normal pointers where casting `const` to `non-const` would allow to modify the value, but I don't see the point here, where const-correctness is checked in function definition, before such assignment.

Comment: Semantically, you are correct that there is no problem. A function that takes `(const Foo *x, const Bar *y)` could, in principle, be cast to a function that takes `(Foo *x, Bar *y)` without risk of violating const-correctness. But as the answers say, in C++ these `const` declarations are part of the function signature, which is used for overload resolution, name mangling, etc. So the language forbids it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-static member functions have an extra hidden `this` parameter. Given the existence of that that extra hidden parameter, a non-static `void A::f() const;` behaves much like `void A__f(const A *__this)`, and the behaviour you see for member functions models the behaviour for non-member functions.

```
void f(void *);
void (*pf)(const void *) = f; // also an error
```

As for whether it could break on any implementation, I suppose in theory, an implementation is permitted to read a `void *` parameter from a different register than a `const void *`  parameter, and if so, the result of the conversion (were it valid) could not be used to call `f` properly. I have no idea why any implementor would make such a decision, and I don't know of any real implementation that does so, but it's one allowed by the standard.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the reason why pointers to member functions, can't point to const member functions?

Because the `const` modifier is part of the *function signature*. Once you declare a function pointer, that function pointer can only be used to assign pointers to function that have the same function signature.